# SwiftUI - centre content on a List

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

How can I make this arrow on the centre of the list?

```
struct ProductsList : View {
var body: some View {

    VStack {
        List {
            Image(systemName: "shift")


        }

    }
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You may just wanna use some Spacers.

```
struct ProductList : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                HStack {
                   Spacer()
                   Image(systemName: "shift")
                   Spacer()
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I would suggest to use ViewModifier:

```
struct CenterModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            content
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

so that in your list, if you have more different type of UI elements its more convenient way to do so:

```
struct ExampleList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Image(systemName: "shift").modifier(CenterModifier())
            SomeOtherView().modifier(CenterModifier())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Image(systemName: "shift")
            }.frame(width: geometry.size.width)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

View modifier:

```swift
import SwiftUI

private struct CenterHorizontallyModifier: ViewModifier {

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()
            content
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

extension View {

    func centerHorizontally() -> some View {
        modifier(CenterHorizontallyModifier())
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
struct ExampleList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Image(systemName: "shift").centerHorizontally()
        }
    }
}
```

I can't comment yet, but this is an improved version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61116024/14009088)